# Global Variable in Spring MVC

Tags: java

I want to Store HashMap as global variable in Spring MVC. I use ServletContextListner to fix this. but it's not work properly. i'am using java 8.72 and spring 3

I tried use servlet context listner to slove this problem. i create class and it's implement to the ServletContextListener interface and configer in web.xml in correctly. and next i create hashmap and set it to the servlet context as context attribute.

In controller i can use it but there is no previously putted data in hashmap. how can i fix this.

```
//My listener class public static HashMap loginusers=new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("Loginuser", loginusers);
    System.out.print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
// This sysout is print on console.

}
}

//------------Use loginusers hashmap in controller------------------

HashMap logcheck=(HashMap)context.getAttribute("Loginuser");
```

Comment: Why are you posting this [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56486849/2970947)?

Answer (score 2):

Any @Component (@Controller and @RestController) is singleton. In theory, they act as a global variable. Creating a HashMap inside one of them (Using @AfterPropertiesSet or @PostConstruct) will make it available everywhere.

Another way is to make a @Bean (with specific @Qualifier) of type HashMap in a @Configuration class. This bean (when @Autowire-d with @Qualifier), will be available everywhere.